# R change factors levels of a variable, and remove old ones

Tags: r, spss, levels

I have a large data set, which is read from `SPSS` file. It contains several rows and columns, read from many small `SPSS` files. The SPSS file contained some mistakes, which I want to correct in R. When the data is read, it and has all noises in factor levels, but data is ok in SPSS. I cannot change factor levels in many individual files in SPSS. Following is the small sample of data that I have

```
data
    a  b                   c                  d    e
[1] 3  5 1 Very dissatisfied                  5    5
[2] 8  3                  10         Don't Know    1
[3] 7  5                   3                  8    6
[4] 3  5                   9                  6   99
[5] 9  4                   8  10 Very Satisfied    3
[6] 5 NA       99 Don't Know     Very Satisfied   10

levels(data[,1])
 [1] "1 Very Dissatisfied" "2"                 "3"             "4"                
 [5] "5"                   "6"                 "7"             "8"                
 [9] "9"                   "1" "10 Very Satisfied" "99 Don't know"
[12] "1 Very Bad"        "99"       "2 Satisfied"             "10"
```

The levels contains many mistakes. I want to correct them to something like following

```
x<-factor()
x<-ordered(x,levels=c("1 Very Dissatisfied","2 Satisfied","3 Satisfied","4 Satisfied",
"5 Satisfied","6 Satisfied","7 Satisfied","8 Satisfied","9 Satisfied","10 Very Satisfied",
"99 Dont Know"))

levels(x)
[1] "1 Very Dissatisfied"  "2 Satisfied"         "3 Satisfied"    "4 Satisfied"      
[5] "5 Satisfied"          "6 Satisfied"         "7 Satisfied"    "8 Satisfied"      
[9] "9 Satisfied"          "10 Very Satisfied"  "99 Dont Know"
```

I tried following code

```
for(j in c(1,2,5)){
    data[,j] <- factor(data[,j], levels = c(levels(data[,j]), levels(x)))
    for(i in 2:9){
        data[grep(i,data[,j]),j] <- paste(i,"Satisfied")}
}
```

This does not work. Please show me where I am wrong, and what should I do.

Even after this code works, I have to remove unused garbage factors that the variable contains. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Clean your data. This will only leave numbers and NA.

   ```
   data=apply(data,1:2,function(x) gsub("[^0-9]", "",x))
   ```

   Data will be like this:

   ```
         a   b   c    d    e   

   [1,] "3" "5" "1"  "5"  "5"     
   [2,] "8" "3" "10" "99" "1"   
   [3,] "7" "5" "3"  "8"  "6"   
   [4,] "3" "5" "9"  "6"  "99"  
   [5,] "9" "4" "8"  "10" "3"   
   [6,] "5" NA  "99" "10" "10"
   ```
2. Recode your string.

   ```
   # Install the car package
   install.packages("car")


   # Load the car package     
   library("car")

   replace_string=function(x) {  
   recode(x,'1="1 Very Dissatisfied";  
             2="2 Satisfied";  
             3="3 Satisfied";  
             4="4 Satisfied";   
             5="5 Satisfied";  
             6="6 Satisfied";  
             7="7 Satisfied";  
             8="8 Satisfied";  
             9="9 Satisfied";  
            10="10 Very Satisfied";   
            99="99 Dont Know"')  
    }  

    data=apply(data,1:2,replace_string)
   ```

Comment: Your answer is nice but does not apply very well to me because my data contains noises. I used another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest leaving SPSS attributes as is by not using value labels from SPSS:

```
temp <- read.spss(file, use.value.labels = FALSE)
```

Then I would use `ifelse` to correct the labels based on your for loop:

```
temp$c <- ifelse(as.numeric(temp$c) %in% 1:9, paste(temp$c, "Satisfied", sep=" "), temp$c)
```

Comment: There are many columns which is read correctly from SPSS as factor, and there are still many columns, that are not correct factor. My question is can we selectively read columns using `use.value.labels=TRUE/FALSE` from SPSS to apply your suggestion?

Comment: Without the files, its really tough to say. In my experience I have found that factors should be avoided at all costs except when plotting. I prefer to keep vectors as characters to reduce headaches but that's just what works for me.

Comment: I use this data to plot, and it generates lot of noises, so I want to factor them correctly

Answer (score 0):

The point where I made mistake was in grep. I used `grep(^i$,data)` instead of `grep(i,data)`. This captured both 1 and 10, also 9 and 99. I used `^i$` to exactly match the character so that `^9$` captured only 9 and not 99.

To remove unused levels in factor and use it as ordinal variable, i used `ordered(data)` at the end and that solved the problem.

**I used exact following code to correct myself:**

Step1: Define levels of the factor

```
x<-factor()
x<-ordered(x,levels=c("1 Very Dissatisfied","2 Satisfied","3 Satisfied","4 Satisfied","5 Satisfied","6 Satisfied","7 Satisfied","8 Satisfied","9 Satisfied","10 Very Satisfied","Dont Know"))
```

Step2: Now loop through all the data column and row wise.

I used following code:

```
for(j in c(28,29,32)){
    data[,j]<-factor(data[,j])
    #add required levels so that when introduced later, does not introduce NA
    data[,j] <- factor(data[,j], levels = c(levels(data[,j]), levels(x)))
    #Now remove and correct noises
    data[grep("99",data[,j]),j] <- "Dont Know"
    data[grep("Don",data[,j]),j] <- "Dont Know"
    data[grep("Very [Ss]",data[,j]),j] <- "10 Very Satisfied"
    data[grep("10",data[,j]),j] <- "10 Very Satisfied"
    data[grep("Very [Dd]",data[,j]),j] <- "1 Very Dissatisfied"
    data[grep("^1$",data[,j]),j] <- "1 Very Dissatisfied"
    #Loop through remaining data and correct
    for(i in 2:9){
       data[grep(paste("^",i,"$",sep=""),data[,j]),j] <- paste(i,"Satisfied")
    }
    #to remove unused factors, ordered
    data[,j]<-ordered(data[,j],levels(x))
}
```